# X forwarding on iOS client

Tags: ios, ssh

I want to control a GUI app on my Raspberry Pi 2 (Raspbian) via SSH X forwarding with my iOS device. I heard that both the client and the server need to have X. So is there an app or a way to do this on iOS. Or should I use another method?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can consider using TeamViewer or any alternatives. To build some GUI remote controlling is really complicated and you need to care too much things, like NAT, firewalls...